# AWS Amplify - Cannot read property 'service' of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I want to create a new function in the CLI with *amplify add function*. Unfortunately, it fails with the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
at /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/service-walkthroughs/execPermissionsWalkthrough.js:70:184
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at Object.askExecRolePermissionsQuestions (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/service-walkthroughs/execPermissionsWalkthrough.js:70:47)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Object.createWalkthrough (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/service-walkthroughs/lambda-walkthrough.js:48:78)
at async addFunctionResource (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/provider-utils/awscloudformation/index.js:77:9)
at async Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-function/lib/index.js:252:5)
at async executePluginModuleCommand (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/execution-manager.js:164:5)
at async Object.executeCommand (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/execution-manager.js:35:9)
at async Object.run (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/index.js:116:9)
```

It just stopped working, I created functions a few weeks ago.